# Issue with ASMX webservice url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

I am trying to call a webservice which is as below:

http://localhost:1591/CMSPages/WebService.asmx/GetMediaDetails

The above url works fine. But when i invoke the above url webservice through application, it changes the url

from

> http://localhost:1591/CMSPages/WebService.asmx/GetMediaDetails

To

```
http://localhost:1591/CMSPages/en-us/WebService.asmx/GetMediaDetails
```

An extra

> "en-us"

will be added in application while it get called.

I cannot prevent adding the "en-US" in the application while calling webservice, because it is the needed feature in the application.

All i can do is change the webservice url pattern. Could you please help in achieving this?

My code as below:

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "GetMediaDetails")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]   
public MediaKitResponse GetMediaDetails(int nodeId, string cultureCode)
{
   ////..............some ...code....///
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLogProvider.LogEvent(EventType.ERROR, "GetMediaDetails", "GetMediaDetails", eventDescription: ex.ToString());
        return null;
    }
    return objMediaKit;
}
```

}

Comment: Why your application needs to change the url of service? What is the importance of language in the url of service? Can this be any other language too?

Comment: I think they using a multilanguage application, hence the application setting automatically adds language code. it should be other languages too.